# Selecting only 500 rows from table in R

Tags: r, select, rsqlite

I am using RSQLite package for database operations. For selecting data from table, I used the following code, but I got only 500 rows. Actually this table contains 1200+ rows for that query. What is the cause of this problem?

```
library('RSQLite')
lite <- dbDriver("SQLite", max.con = 25)
db <- dbConnect(lite, dbname = "pf.db")
res <- dbSendQuery(db, paste("SELECT ticker from RUS1000 where portDate='1995-12-29'  ",sep=""))
data <- fetch(res)
print(data)
```

Comment: Can you post the file so we can try to replicate the problem?

Comment: What does `dim(data)` give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `data <- fetch(res,n=-1)`. This will fetch all rows.

Answer (score 3):

or try the easy way

```
data <- dbGetQuery.....
```